# Enviar Parametros y Redireccionar a otra pagina con Ajax o Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

buenas amigos tengo uan enorme duda al momento de **enviar los parametros y redireccionar a otra pagina** aqui esta mi codigo

**Pagina Ejemplo1.php**

```
  <?php
     $var1=1;
     $var2=2;
      echo "<a id='anclka'>
          <input type='text' name='var1' id='var1' value='$var1'>
          <input type='text' name='var2' id='var2' value='$var2'>
      Irme a otra pagina</a>";
   ?>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

     <script>
       $("#anclka").click(function () {
        var var1 = $("#var1").val();
        var var2 = $("#var2").val();
          $.ajax({
          url:'recibo.php',
          data:{var1:var1,var2:var2},
          type:'POST',
          datatype:'json'

        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

         console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente." );

        })
         .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus)
         })

      });
     </script>
```

Comment: Me parece que falta la pregunta...

Comment: ¿Y la duda es...? Algunos no disponemos de telepatía telemática a mano...

Comment: Intento enviarla los datos a la otra página y redireccionar la página al mismo tiempo hacia (**recibo.PHP**)

Comment: En la otra página **recibo.PHP** recibo los valores de la siguiente manera... $var1=$_POST['var1'];      $var2=$_POST['var2'];

Comment: Aclara, por favor, cuál de las dos tareas lograste completar y, en caso de error, descríbelo o al menos menciona el mensaje que obtienes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   $("#anclka").click(function () {
    var var1 = $("#var1").val();
    var var2 = $("#var2").val();
      $.ajax({
      url:'recibo.php',
      data:{var1:var1,var2:var2},
      type:'POST',
      datatype:'json'

    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

     console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente." );
     window.location.href = "aqui pagina que se desea redireccionar";
    })
     .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus)
     })

  });
 </script>
```